# Guardar gráfica completa utilizando matplotlib en Python

Tags: python, matplotlib

Al intentar guardar una gráfica generada a partir de una serie de puntos, la imagen generada me sale cortada, es decir, aparece por ejemplo solo una parte de la denominación de los ejes. ¿Alguien sabe como ajustar esto? El código sería aproximadamente el siguiente:

```
f, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(10, 10))
plt.rc('font', size = 7)
corr = df1_number.corr()
sb.heatmap(corr, mask=np.zeros_like(corr, dtype=np.bool), 
cmap=sb.diverging_palette(220, 10, as_cmap=True),square=True, ax=ax)
plt.savefig("Correlaciones Pearson.jpg")
```

Comment: Prueba con `plt.savefig("Correlaciones Pearson.jpg", dpi=f.dpi, bbox_inches='tight')`. Si no da resultado o no es lo que buscas,  ¿Sería posible que agregaras la imagen he indicaras que es lo que está fallando en concreto en base a ella?

Comment: Perfecto! Me solucionó el problema, que es lo que hacen específicamente esos argumentos?

Comment: La clave está en `bbox_inches`, he creado una respuesta con un pequeño ejemplo para mostrarlo. `dpi` permite especificar la resolución de la imagen en puntos por pulgada.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Puedes usar el argumento opcional de [`bbox_inches`](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.savefig.html) que permite especificar que porción de la figura ha de ser guardada. Si se pasa `'tight'` al argumento se extiende o reduce el área de la figura guardada para incluir a todos los componentes de ella, eliminado también los espacios blancos sobrantes en los bordes.

Es decir, deberías usar:

```
plt.savefig("Correlaciones Pearson.jpg", bbox_inches='tight')
```

Un ejemplo reproducible:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

matplotlib.rcParams.update({'font.size': 21})
ax = plt.gca()

ax2 = ax.twinx()
for i in range(10):
    ax.bar(i, np.random.randint(1000))

plt.ylabel('Datos')
plt.savefig("Ejemplo1.jpg")
```

Esto nos va a guardar algo como:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Y la etiqueta?

Si usamos:

```
plt.savefig("Ejemplo.jpg", bbox_inches='tight')
```

obtenemos lo que queremos:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

---

`show` nos puede producir el mismo problema. Aunque redimensionado la ventana podemos llegar a verlo todo, en este caso llamar previamente a `plt.tight_layout()`/`figure.tight_layout()` lo resulve.